# How to use multiple pthreads to evaluate expression from a program

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to use pthread to solve an expression by breaking down it into threads.

My questions is:- If an expression like (a+b)+(c+d)+(e+f) to be evaluated using pthreads such that:-

1. Create 3 threads where first expression (a+b) is evaluated by 1st thread, (c+d) evaluated by second thread and (e+f) evaluated by 3rd thread.
2. Value of all the above variables is '1', so, the final answer of the expression evaluation should come as '6'.
3. the third thread should be executed at last which will print final output as '6'.

Then how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse the expression, you'll get an abstract syntax tree like the following:

```
                  +
                 / \
                +   +
               / \ / \
              +  + e  f
             / \ |\
             a b c d
```

You can partition the problem into threads at the nodes of the syntax tree. When evaluating a node, you can give the two different subproblems (left and right subtree) to two different threads. Each of the subthreads can repeat the pattern until you have parallelized the tree sufficiently. In code, this might look like:

```
int evaluate_subtree_threaded(node_t* parent_node)
{
   int left_result, right_result;
   pthread_t thread;

   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, evaluate_subtree_threaded, parent_node->left);
   right_result = evaluate_subtree(parent_node->right);
   pthread_join(thread, &left_result);
   return left_result + right_result;
}
```

Note how this code snippet blatantly assumes that actual evaluation logic is in `evaluate_subtree` and ignores all types.

Of course, be aware that thread creation is much more expensive than evaluating an expression.

Comment: Thanks thiton. I will work on this logic using the syntax tree you have explained. Thanks a lot!! :)